# Google analytics not working on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics

I'm had just implemented google analysis and run the app on one of my iOS devices. However, Real time reporting still showing **everything 0**. I had setup the google analysis as below. Appreciated if any suggestion is given.

**AppDelegate.swift** didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method : -

```
    guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
        assert(false, "Google Analytics not confiugured correctly.")
    }
    gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "UA-10317xxxx-1")
    // Optional: automatically report uncaught exceptions.
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true
```

**LoginVC.swift** viewWillAppear method : -

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    setupTracker()
}
```

**LoginVC.swift** setupTracker() method : -

```
private func setupTracker() {
    let name = "Login VC"
    guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker else { return }
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: name)

    guard let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView() else { return }
    tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}
```

Comment: you need to set the default tracker in app delegate. `gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "UA-10317xxxx-1")` will return a tracker object and set it to `GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker`

Comment: I had set gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "my tracking id") on appDelegate method but its still not working

Comment: is it I still missing something on app delegate ?

Comment: you are missing this line. 

`GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker = gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "UA-10317xxxx-1") ` need to set your tracker to default tracker to get it working

Comment: still showing 0 users on google analysis dashboard , I had checked tracker.set(screenName , value: name) is being called and builder too. am I need to wait for google analysis to be update later ..?

Comment: enable GAI logger loglevel to `kGAILogLevelVerbose` and check the logs in console that GA actually sending hit to GA server or not. Usually for me real time count is not accurate and it is always take some to get result on GA dashboard

Comment: @Bluewings thanks! it's working now suddenly.

Comment: Great! I will submit it as the answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set the default tracker of `GAI` in app delegate like below.

```
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker = gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "<<Trakcing Key goes here>>")
```

Also to understand what is happening in background we can always check the logs by setting GAI logger level to `kGAILogLevelVerbose`

Real-time count and almost all GA features are not exactly the real time for me. We might need to give it some time to see the hits in GA dashboard. Typically 10-15 mins